# PHPUnit in Eclipse Fatal Error

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, phpunit, makegood

I am currently working on setting up php unit testing on windows in eclipse with the version

> Version: Juno Service Release 2
>   Build id: 20130225-0426

Here is the fatal error that I am getting when running "run all tests" from eclipse.

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Util_Configuration' not found in C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.0.v201407050319\resources\php\vendor\piece\stagehand-testrunner\src\DependencyInjection\PHPUnitConfigurationFactory.php on line 70

More Information.

- I have also installed the Eclipse Plugin PHP Tool Integration.
- I have installed Eclipse Plugin MakeGood
- I have installed PEAR, and pointed the php library include to the PEAR location

I Also downloaded the source code of PHPUnit from the git repo, and set the attribute testSuiteLoaderFile to a source file in the git repo, because it didn't seem that the file was located anywhere on my system, but it was supposed to be.

**phpunit.xml snippet**

```
testSuiteLoaderFile="C:/Users/Gary/phpunit-bundle/PHPUnit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MakeGood 3.1.0 does not support Juno. Use Luna or Kepler, and see [PHPUnit backward compatibility issues](https://github.com/piece/makegood/releases/tag/v3.0.0).